WPF combo box nothing shows for selected item
Hi I have a problem in display selected item of combo box in a data grid. in this code nothing show in combo box as selected item.
this is my xaml :
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.GridTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                                          SelectedItem="{Binding GridType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                                          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxFlatStyle}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

this is my code behind:
        public DatumManagerMainWindow(Models.DatumManager datumManager)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainWindowViewModel mainViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(datumManager);

            this.DataContext = mainViewModel;

            dtg_xGrids.ItemsSource = mainViewModel.HorizontalGrids;
            dtg_yGrids.ItemsSource = mainViewModel.VerticalGrids;

        }

and this is my view model:
    internal class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DatumGrid> HorizontalGrids { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<DatumGrid> VerticalGrids { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<DatumLevel> Levels { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<DatumGridType> GridTypes { get; set; }  // Add this property

        public MainWindowViewModel(Models.DatumManager datumManager)
        {
            var datumSystem = datumManager.GetDatumSystem();
            HorizontalGrids = datumSystem.HorizontalGrids;
            VerticalGrids = datumSystem.VerticalGrids;
            Levels = datumSystem.Levels;

            GridTypes = datumManager.GetDatumGridTypes();

        }
    }

and this is my model:
    public class DatumGrid : Datum
    {
        public int Id { get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DatumGridType GridType { get; set; }
        public DatumGridDirection Direction { get; }
        public double Ordinate { get; set; }

        public DatumGrid(int id, string name, DatumGridType gridType, DatumGridDirection direction, double ordinate)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            GridType = gridType;
            Direction = direction;
            Ordinate = ordinate;
        }
    }

and i want to display name of DatumGridType with this class:
    public class DatumGridType
    {
        public int Id { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public DatumGridType( int id,string name) 
        {            
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }

please help me . thanks
I can see any selected item in my combo boxes.

The SelectedItem object must compare equal to an element in the ItemsSource collection. If the GridType value is not contained in the GridTypes collection, you could override the Equals method of the DatumGridType class.

Can you please elaborate more on the problem? Your ComboBox displays items in the dropdown? But when you select an item by clicking it then SelectedItem is not set? And nothing is showing in the text field of the ComboBox? Or are you setting SelectedItem programmatically?

Your ComboBox is "detached" from your DataGrid (which appears to be detached from your "view model"). Instead of "templating" a CB in a column, you should have used a "DataGrid ComboBox Column" to get off on the right foot. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
